# Rstudio and R terminal give different outputs

Tags: r, unique, rstudio

In Rstudio (using R 3.1.1) when I run this,

```
length(unique(sort(c(outer(2:100,2:100,"^")))))
# 9220
```

In R 3.1.1 when I run this,

```
length(unique(sort(c(outer(2:100,2:100,"^")))))
# 9183
```

(the correct output is 9183)

I can't figure out why... help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post `sessionInfo()` from both just to confirm versions/builds?

Comment: I think it is a difference between 32 bit and 64 bit versions. You are running 64 on Rstudio and 32 on the regular R. In Rstudio go to Tools -> Global Options -> R version -> Change -> change to 32 bit version of 3.1.1 and run your code again

Comment: I get 9220 running this in R 3.1.2 (64-bit) in both RStudio and R terminal, and 9183 when I run it in 32-bit... Confirming @DavidArenburg's suggestion

Comment: I guess the answer is [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-2-12-1-Windows-32bit-and-64bit-are-numerical-differences-expected-td3299000.html) somewhere between the lines in Profs Ripley answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David Arenburg notes, this is a difference between 32-bit and 64-bit R versions, at least on Windows machines. Presumably, some sort of rounding error is involved. Interestingly, it is the 32-bit R gets the answer right, whereas the 64-bit R finds too many unique numbers.

First to confirm that `9183` is indeed the correct answer, I used the `gmp` package (a wrapper for the C multiple precision arithmetic library GMP), which provides results that are not subject to rounding errors:

```
library(gmp)
x <- as.bigz(2:100)
length(unique(do.call(c, sapply(x, function(X) x^X))))
[1] 9183
```

Here are the results from my 32-bit R:

```
length(unique(sort(c(outer(2:100,2:100,"^")))))
# [1] 9183
R.version[1:7]               _                           
# platform       i386-w64-mingw32            
# arch           i386                        
# os             mingw32                     
# system         i386, mingw32               
# status                                     
# major          3                           
# minor          1.2
```

And here are the results from my 64-bit R:

```
length(unique(sort(c(outer(2:100,2:100,"^")))))
# [1] 9220
R.version[1:7]
# platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
# arch           x86_64                      
# os             mingw32                     
# system         x86_64, mingw32             
# status                                     
# major          3                           
# minor          1.2
```

Comment: Do most people use the 32-bit version of R for reasons like this?+

Comment: @nathanesau -- No. Seeing any difference between the versions is really uncommon (which is probably why your question is getting so many votes). And in arenas where that sort of rounding error has any possibility of importantly affecting results, folks (should) use add-on packages that support higher-precision computations.